# Contentful: how to query entries that have one of either entries attached?

Tags: php, api, contentful

I'm trying to filter blog posts based on 2 or more categories.

The blog posts are a content type and the categories are as well. Each blog post can have only one category. The category is connected to the post via a reference field. I'd like the user to be able to filter the posts. The user can select multiple categories at once.

It seems I'm unable to fabricate the query. Here's what I have so far:

```
// PHP
$categories = ["79RwpuYXo4W9FiYMdpeShj", "4CAkZRYSa3EB23ipTwZ92R"];
$query = (new Query)
    ->setContentType('blogPosts')
    ->where('fields.postCategory.sys.id', $categories, 'in'); // using 'all' instead of 'in' also doesn't return any results
```

In my mind, this should get all blog posts that hold a reference to either category entry (id). However, no entries are returned using this query. I'm using [contentful/laravel v4.0](https://github.com/contentful/contentful-laravel).

Comment: Do you need $ sign for categories variable in last line? Also check out Sequences in doc below https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/android/tutorials/advanced-filtering-and-searching/

Comment: Sorry, that's just a typo here in the question. Fixing that now.

Comment: Does it return anything without filtering on categories? If so may be pass $categories as comma delimited string instead of array..

Comment: Tried that too without any luck. What works is if I ask for only one category ID. However, I can't imagine that Contentful can't deliver such a simple request (multiple categories). And yes, if I omit the `where()` altogether I get all blog posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out. I'm using [Contentful Core v2](https://github.com/contentful/contentful-core.php/blob/master/UPGRADE-2.0.md). The correct query structure for v2 is the following:

```
// PHP
$categories = ["79RwpuYXo4W9FiYMdpeShj", "4CAkZRYSa3EB23ipTwZ92R"];
$query = (new Query)
    ->setContentType('blogPosts')
    ->where('fields.postCategory.sys.id[in]', $categories);
```

Comment: Nice, I wonder why would they change the “contract” of their api between version like that.. kind of goes against principles of api design.. what if you wanted to upgrade and it all broke.. but the idea of headless CMS is intriguing https://link.medium.com/OqXauUOIkU

Comment: I suppose you need to pay attention to breaking changes in major version updates.